# Open fragment on button click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello basically i'm trying to open a new fragment from an existing fragment via a Button click. Please help ! I am very new to android.Any help is appreciated.

[This is my code so far](https://codeshare.io/5XoDZl)

I have added this code to the end of my file but still it not works.

```
    Button btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFragment1);
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnFragment1:
                FragmentHome home = new FragmentHome();  //this is your new fragment.
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, home);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);// it will anim while calling fragment.
                ft.addToBackStack(null); // it will manage back stack of fragments.
                ft.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where will going to be shown this fragment into an Activity or normal Fragment ?

Comment: From one fragment to another fragment  @Spritzig

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope if it works.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnFragment1:
             FragmentHome nextFrag= new FragmentHome();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag, "findThisFragment")
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
        break:
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check i can't see any changes and still the same problem i'm getting

Comment: Which problem are you facing what does the logs show?